# Can I use broadcasting in ArrayFire?

Tags: arrayfire

Can I do something like this:

```
auto minEl = min(a);
a -= minEl;
```

?

I get an unknown af::exception when I do that. For now, I'm doing this:

```
auto minEl = *min(a).host<float>();
a -= minEl;
```

But of course, it does an unnecessary download.

I borrow the term "broadcasting" from numpy, because there it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayFire does not currrently support broadcasting. You would have to manually tile the array to match the required dimensions.
`auto minEl = min(a);
a -= tile(minEl, a.dims(0));`

This method also avoids the copy of the scalar to host memory.